# How to generate test data for mongodb in bulk which has reference to different collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a Node.JS project with Mongodb as a database. I want to test how the api performs when the db collection has thousands of documents in it.

So I'm trying to fill the collection with test data but the problem here is, I've multiple associations for a single collections, i.e multiple reference fields in collection.

So is there any api available which allows me to generate data that supports reference fields too.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old library for creating dummy data in mongoose: [mongoose-dummy](https://github.com/thedgmbh/mongoose-dummy). But it doesn't look like it handles referenced documents.

You can also use [faker](https://github.com/faker-js/faker) to create eg. addresses, emails, names, numbers etc.

This is one of those things you really need to DIY (though you can use the above libraries to make it easier)

You created your application and models. Only you will be able to make realistic test data. For example, you will need to decide how many documents to create for a comment model on a blog post model based on what either historical data or your expectations if none exists.

Comment: Yes @caffeinated.tech, referenced docs is the issue here. Just tell me your opinion on this. I'm planning to provide a UI from which I could select required values for referenced documents and number of records to be inserted. So then I can create JSON dynamically and bulk insert the json data in mongo db collection. Is this a good approch?

Comment: That sounds good. UI would be optional to me, I would just hardcode the numbers as it wouldn't be used often - but I'm making assumptions on your setup here, you will know if you need a UI. When doing bulk inserts, do them in batches of maybe 500-1000 documents at a time, then nothing should take longer than a second and you should know immediately if something goes wrong

Comment: yes, thanks for the validation @caffeinated.tech. Inserting in batches is way more easier. And we can insert data which is kind of real and referenced docs issue also gets fixed.